# module 'urllib.request' has no attribute 'type'

Tags: python, aws-lambda, urllib

I am trying to build a AWS lambda function using python3.8. Previously, it was using python2.7 and worked fine. However, post upgrading it to 3.8, I ran into below error:

```
Function Logs
START RequestId: 911b556a-44ea-4f54-a328-ec35d256b2bc Version: $LATEST
GenericError!!
module 'urllib.request' has no attribute 'type'
END RequestId: 911b556a-44ea-4f54-a328-ec35d256b2bc
```

Code:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import boto3
import urllib.request
import urllib.error
from urllib import *
import base64
from io import StringIO
import logging
import os
from botocore.client import Config
import datetime
import time
import hashlib

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    class HashMD5Exception(Exception):
        pass

    url = os.environ['url']
    username = os.environ['username']
    password = os.environ['password']
    fileName = os.environ['fileName']
        
    def FileLoad():
    
        request = urllib.request.Request(url, headers={'accept': '*/*'})
        base64string = base64.b64encode('%s:%s' % (username, password))
        base64byte = base64string.encode('utf-8')
        #request.add_header('Authorization', 'Basic %s' % base64string)
        request.add_header('Authorization', 'Basic %s' % base64byte)
        urlHash = hashlib.md5()
        dloadHash = hashlib.md5()

        try:
            result = urllib.request.urlopen(request)

            if result.code == 200:
                print ('url connection is successful!')
            else:
                print('Error!!')

        except Exception as e:

            print('GenericError!!')
                print(str(e))
```

Not sure what I am missing here. Thanks.

After some debugging I did get some success however, ended up with new error below:

```
GenericError!!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/wclambdatest.py", line 42, in lambda_handler
    result = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 222, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 531, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 640, in http_response
    response = self.parent.error(
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 569, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 502, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 649, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized
```

If I just connect the url using username/password in header it works as per below code however, it throws above 401:Unauthorized error when trying to download file from the url.

Updated code:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import boto3
import urllib.request
import urllib.error
from urllib.request import urlopen
from urllib.error import HTTPError
from urllib.error import URLError
import base64
from io import StringIO
import logging
import os
from botocore.client import Config
import datetime
import time
import hashlib
import traceback

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    url = os.environ['url']
    username = os.environ['username']
    password = os.environ['password']
    fileName = os.environ['fileName']
    
    request = urllib.request.Request(url, headers={'accept': '*/*'})
    base64string = (('%s:%s' % (username, password))).encode("utf-8")
    base64byte = base64.b64encode(base64string)
    request.add_header('Authorization', 'Basic %s' % base64byte)

    try:
   
        result = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
        print (result.getcode())

    except Exception as e:
    
        print('GenericError!!')
        print(traceback.format_exc())
```

Comment: Is this the complete code? Because there is no call to `request.type` and so I cannot tell where the error lose. Could you post the traceback of this error as an edit?

Comment: Well, its says content has only code and asking me to add more details hence, pasted the required code only. However, I have edited and added some more details of code and error. 
Also I am no where calling `request.type` but not sure how is it throwing that error?

Comment: Can you add the traceback? Just pasting the error is not sufficient to identify the issue. Also add the complete code, at least the full try-except clause.

Comment: Well, I am afraid that it doesn't provide traceback. It gives only function log error which I have pasted above. Also updated code with except block.

Comment: Is there some way in which you can debug the code/ look at the output after adding some print statements? That will help to narrow it down.

Comment: @SagarJadhav In the except block, instead of `print(str(e))`, put `import traceback; print(traceback.format_exc())`, you will be able to print the traceback.

Comment: Thanks @Shiva for the suggestion. Yes, it's giving traceback output as below;
`GenericError!!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/wclambdatest.py", line 38, in lambda_handler
    result = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 222, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 516, in open
    protocol = req.type
AttributeError: module 'urllib.request' has no attribute 'type'`

Comment: HTTP 401 is a sign that your creds are probably incorrect. Have you tested the url from your local machine with creds you are using in AWS Lambda?

Answer (score 0):

In your imports at the top, remove `from urllib import *`, that's causing the error.

---

Below is a probable cause of the error, may not be entirely correct:

In Python 2.7, doing `from urllib import *` brings several utility functions into scope. That's not the case with Python 3 where only the modules present inside the urllib package are brought into scope, one of which is `request` module.

On the line `result = urllib.request.urlopen(request)`, you are probably passing the module `request` to `urlopen` and that's why you see the exception - "AttributeError: **module 'urllib.request'** has no attribute 'type'".

But what I don't understand is, on the line - `request = urllib.request.Request(url, headers={'accept': '*/*'})`, you are overriding the `request` module name, so when you pass `request` to `urlopen`, you are actually passing the `Request` object and not the `request` module. So, this error shouldn't occur in the first place.
Are you sure the code you added is complete/correct? Can you check for any typos?

Comment: Well, commenting out `from urllib import *` didn't make any difference. Getting new error:
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/wclambdatest.py", line 40, in lambda_handler
    result = urllib.request.urlopen(urlRequest)
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 222, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 515, in open
    req.timeout = timeout
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'timeout'`

Adding `https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.9/Lib/urllib/request.py`

Comment: I hope you read my answer completely. Are you sure the code you posted is complete and has the same import statements and variable names as the code you are running on your machine? What do you mean by 'Adding https://github.com/python.....' in your above comment?

Comment: Yes, it was a complete code which I have pasted earlier but due to character limit couldn't paste the updated code inside the previous comment section. I have made some progress by updating import statements and base64encode (encoding string into bytes).
One thing I noticed if I connect the url using username/password code works however, if I try to download the file from url its gives me error:
`urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized`

Comment: You can update our question with the updated code, you are not limited to a comment for updates.

Comment: @SagarJadhav. As I said in the above comment, you can update your question with the updated code. It's difficult to read multi-line code in comments. Please read the comment properly before posting.

Comment: Yes, I have now updated my question with the updated code. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

I have managed to resolved the issue now. 401:unauthorized error is resolved by using `ascii` encoding/decoding instead of `utf-8`.

Here is the final code:

```
request = urllib.request.Request(url, headers={'accept': '*/*'})
base64string = (('%s:%s' % (username, password))).encode("ascii")
base64byte = base64.b64encode(base64string)
request.add_header('Authorization', 'Basic {}'.format(base64byte.decode("ascii")))

    try:
        result = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
        ## Read the downloaded xml file as a string...
        #print (result.read().decode('utf-8'))
        
        if result.getcode() == 200:
            print ('Url connection is successful!')

    except Exception as e:
    
        print('GenericError!!')
        print(traceback.format_exc()
```

Comment: This isn't the answer to the original question.